# Updating number of columns in TableModel

Tags: swing, jtable

i use a DataModel which extends an AbstractTableModel for my Jtable.
When i use the constructor `JTable main = new JTable(model);`
everything works fine but when i add columns to my DataModel and call `this.fireTableStructureChanged()` the number of columns does not update as can be seen in the following example.

[image: Example]

It shows a JTable initialised with my DataModel, which contained 3 rows and 3 columns. The DataModel has been updated to 4 rows and  4 columns but does only show 3 columns.

My Changeevent seems to be wrong because:

```
JTable.getColumnCount() shows 3
but DataModel.getColumnCount() shows 4
```

How can i tell the Table that the number of columns has changed and it should repaint them?

Comment: Please show us your code. Otherwise it will be plain guessing what could cause this issue. For a clean test program it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JTable also has a TableColumnModel which holds all the columns to show. When you add another column to your model, the column model still has the old number of columns unless the table's `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` property is set to true (`table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(true)`).

The other way would be to manually add another column to the column model.

Comment: Thanks but setting setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel() to true seems to have no effect it JTable.getColumnCount() still shows 3. Any Idea why?
However calling JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel() updates the number of columns and therefore solves my problem :)